# How to get Thymeleaf to process html in the static folder?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yeoman, thymeleaf

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get `index.html` to be process by Thymeleaf in:

```
src/main/resources/static
```

Thymeleaf works perfectly in the templates directory with no configuration:

```
src/main/resources/templates
```

The environment is Spring Boot with Maven. It uses Yeoman to transpile the `index.html`, CSS and JS. and I need all those files to be in the same directory tree.

IDK if this is enough info, but below is my `ThymeleafConfig`:

```
package org.jeremu.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        Set<ITemplateResolver> resolvers = new HashSet<ITemplateResolver>();
        resolvers.add(defaultWebTemplateResolver());
        resolvers.add(emailTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(resolvers);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver defaultWebTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver webTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        webTemplateResolver.setPrefix("static/");
        webTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        webTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        webTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        webTemplateResolver.setOrder(2);
        return webTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("templates/email/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);

        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW I'm using org.thymeleaf » thymeleaf-spring4 2.1.4.RELEASE  which comes default with Spring Boot Thymeleaf Starter » 1.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this setting in your **application.properties** file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that didn't work for me. I attempted   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/   spring.thymeleaf.prefix="classpath:/static/"   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/static/   spring.thymeleaf.prefix=static

Comment: Here is a complete working example of Thymeleaf templates being processed from src/main/resources/static using Spring Boot 1.3.0  https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q37823580

Comment: Oh wow ... it worked! I had my IndexController returning `"forward:/index.html";` when I changed it to `index` it works great! Thank you so much!